# Redshift query timeout in C#

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, amazon-redshift

I have an instance of Redshift on AWS.
My application is running as Windows Service on EC2 in the same region as the Redshift Cluster. I have a query wich takes on average ~45 seconds and redshift apparently has a default timeout of 30 seconds. So after ~30 seconds of this query running I get:

> ERROR: Query (SOME_NUMBER) cancelled on user's request;
>   Error while executing the query

The same query runs and finishes fine in the SQL Workbench/J, so the cluster is configured properly. I tried without any luck:

- to add "CommandTimeout=9000;ConnectionTimeout=9000;" to the connection string
- to set timeout parameter programmaticaly via OdbcConnection -> ConnectionTimeout
- to run "set statement_timeout = 900000;" before the query
- configure cluster parameters

Anyone know how to remove or change default timeout?

Answer (score 1):

This connection string format has worked for me pretty well:

```
Host={Host};Port={Port};Username={Username};Password={Password};SSL Mode=Require;Server Compatibility Mode=Redshift;Timeout=45;Command Timeout={TimeoutSeconds};Tcp Keepalive=true;
```

"Timeout" is the connection timeout
"Command Timeout" is, well, the default command timeout

You can also set the command timeout on the command itself:

```
await using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(commandSql, con) { CommandTimeout = 300 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the keep alive parameter. For the JDBC driver it's `tcpKeepAlive`. Not sure if it has the same name for ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that can occur which may be impacting you is MTU size.  Redshift supports a max MTU of 1500 (this is the max packet size on the network) and most internet connections are also "chunked up" this much to support all the various switches in the path.  However, EC2 instances and AWS networks don't have this limitation and can support larger MTUs and are set to do this by default.  So what can happen is that the EC2 sends a long query and Redshift only sees the first 1500 bytes of it and is waiting for the rest. Both sides waiting on the other.

To resolve you need to change the network configuration of the EC2 instance to an MTU of 1500.  I've don't this many times on Linux EC2s but never for Windows.  So here's a link to the page that looks to describe the process for Windows - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/network_mtu.html#set_mtu_windows

Answer (score 0):

Setting `CommandTimeout` programmatically against the `OdbcCommand` fixed it for me. Setting it in the connection string did not work.

And setting `ConnectionTimeout` does not work, which I assume is because this is just the timeout for making the initial connection.